# Laravel model query array against array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to find eloquent model based on 2 arrays. Basically, I have a model which includes a array field and is stored in a DB.

```
Object 1 : rankings = ['red', 'blue']
Object 2 : rankings = ['orange', 'yellow']
Object 3 : rankings = ['orange', 'purple']
```

The user can select some colors and then wants to find all the object that have at least one color he has slected. Thus, in my controller, I would like to find all the instances that have at least one element of a query array. The colors chosen by the user could be :

```
['blue','yellow','black']
```

In that case, I would expect to get object 1 and 2 but not 3. Is there a way to build such query ?

```
Model::whereIn('rankings', ['blue','yellow','black'])->get();
```

Would not work as rankings is not a single field but an array as well.

Comment: When you say "an array field", what do you mean? Are these arrays stored as strings in column in your database? Is it a JSON field? Or better yet, is it a normalized `pivot` field, etc etc. One of those methods is going to be quite difficult to search against, but the other 2 are much easier...

Comment: It's the first case but I'll specify it a bit better in my post.

Comment: is ranking a string field or json?

Comment: At the moment, it's a string.